# gstreamer faac in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, plugins, gstreamer

Does anyone know how to install the faac plugin for gstreamer on Ubuntu 20.04

I have run

```
$ sudo apt install gstreamer1.0*
```

which installed plugins-good, -base, -bad and -ugly. I am getting

```
$gst-inspect-1.0 faac
No such element or plugin 'faac'
```

Comment: I have same issue on Fedora 33 when trying to setup tools for chromecast. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: `apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio` has not helped either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading and compiling the latest version of soundconverter from the git repo did it for me.

See [here](https://github.com/kassoulet/soundconverter)

Hope this helps.

**Edit.** Details :

```
$ git clone https://github.com/kassoulet/soundconverter.git
$ cd soundconverter
$ sudo python3 setup.py install
```

If it asks to install `python-distutils-extra` take care to install your python version of this package. For me it was `python3-distutils-extra`.

Then you can launch `soundconverter` and it seems to work.

**Edit 2.** There seems to be a simpler way by adding the ppa with

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xtradeb/apps
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

I didn't try it, it shall work.

Comment: adding the repository and updating did not help on my xubuntu 20.04